# Node.js Start on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, meteor

I need to test mi meteor app on WINDOWS, and build that on a simpler node.js app.

On windows, I need to run this an use the command:

```
node main.js
```

But says Error: Must pass options.rootUrl or set ROOT_URL in the server environment.

I try with:

```
ROOT_URL: http://127.0.0.1 node main.js
```

But it says:

```
ROOT_URL= : The term 'ROOT_URL=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set ROOT_URL=http://127.0.0.1
node main.js
```